# Avoid duplicating While-Wend loop in excel vba

Tags: excel, loops, code-duplication, vba

I have a very huge while wend loop in my Excel VBA.

Earlier in the code I set a variable `strMode` to `True` or `False`.

If it is `False` then in my while condition I want to set

```
while var1 + var1previous > 1
```

and if it is `True`

```
while var1 + var1previous > 1 or var1previous+ var1  > 1
```

How can I do that, if I don't what to "double" the While-Wend code, for my `If` statement?

Comment: Parts before and after the `Or` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess what you are trying to do because just like @Gserg mentioned,

your second condition looks the same.

---

I am going to call var1+var1previous>1 condition **Cond_A** and second condition which you used after or **Cond_B**

```
Cond_A = var1+var1previous ' This will be first condition
Cond_B = 0
If strMode then Cond_B = var1+var1previouis 'This will be second condition

While Cond_A > 1 or Cond_B > 1
```

What I did above is that when strMode value is true then you are comparing  both of conditions.

When strmode is false, then since the second condition already set to false

and because of **or** it will just compare Cond_A and loop.

Comment: Thx MutjayLee - var1 and var1previous are changed during the while wend loop, I guess my problem is I don't know how to declare the variable Cond_A and B so that they are read the right way in the while condition. :-/

Comment: MutjayLee - you just gave me an idea there - I can introduce a 0/1 variable and multiply the condition (B) condition to 0 or 1 accordingly and that Works - thx Again - can I give some kind of points ?

Comment: I don't really care about the points. I don't even know what the points are for. I just like helping people solve their problem. And I know I did not solve directly, but I'm glad I could be assist to your problem :)